# C# regular expression not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am having following code but unable to understand as to why no match is returned? What change do I need to make?

```
string temp = "qqqqqqqq<ahref=\"city.php?city=qqqqqqq";
Regex r = new Regex("<ahref=\"city.php?city=");
Match m = r.Match(temp);
```

The variable m doesn't return a match.

Thanks

Varun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not escape the dot `.` and the question mark `?` meta-characters.

```
Regex r = new Regex("<ahref=\"city\\.php\\?city=");
```

Comment: @VVV I just fixed it - you need to double the slashes.